# store the name of a function in a JSON file and later be able to load and call it from within a script?

Tags: javascript, electron, vis.js

That title is kind of garbled and this is probably a duplicate but I've been digging a while. This must be really simple. The accepted answer on this question didn't work for me: [How to declare and use the name of a function from a json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2677394/how-to-declare-and-use-the-name-of-a-function-from-a-json-object)

**The task:** I am trying to externalize the set-up data for a `Vis.js` timeline into a JSON file . The data set was no problem nor are all of the options except for the function references, "orderByID" and "visTemplate". Those are functions I defined which exist within the script where I am working with the JSON data.

When I try to use the JSON without attempting to convert it, `Vis.js` complains. When I tried the answer from the question above with the code below, I get the errors show in the image.

This is in `Electron` and the script is being loaded through a script tag in the index.html.

I await the one-line answer to this simple issue which  have spent so much time describing.

---

```
console.log(' timelineOptions.order', timelineOptions.order);
console.log(' timelineOptions.template', timelineOptions.template);
console.log('this', this);
console.log('window', window);

timelineOptions.order = window[timelineOptions.orderByID];
timelineOptions.template = window[timelineOptions.visTemplate];
```

---

[image]

---

```
 "timelineOptions": {
    "order": "orderByID",
    "selectable": true,
    "zoomable": false,
    "width": "100%",
    "height": "90%",
    "minHeight": 700,
    "format": {
        "minorLabels": {
            "hour": "HH\\h"
        }
    },
    "margin": {
        "axis": 20,
        "item": 20
    },
    "start": "2016-12-30",
    "end": "2017-01-4",
    "template": "visTemplate",
    "showCurrentTime": false,
    "dataAttributes": "all",
    "timeAxis": { "scale": "day", "step": 1 },
    "orientation": {
        "axis": "top",
        "item": "top"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure if you've setup the right reference on the window object but shouldn't your code read:

```
timelineOptions.order = window[timelineOptions.order];
```

You've referenced the string value *orderByID* instead of the property name you used to set the object up.

Comment: Arrgh!! You have good eyes and/or I need to get up and walk around! Thanks for the assist! I actually looked through the properties of the `window` object and didn't see the functions I reference listed - maybe I missed that too.